# How to send confirmation email to customer and set as not confirmed customer in magento programmatically

Tags: email, customer-account

I am trying to send this email in this observer `customer_register_success`

My code:

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
            $customer->setConfirmation(1); //confirmation needed to register?
            $customer->save(); //yes, this is also needed
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmation',$session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),$storeId); //send confirmation email to customer?
$session->logout();
```

Mail is sending but customer is set as confirmed but i want to set as not confirmed